# Add double quotes to the first line of a csv file via command line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line

I have this csv file and I have noticed that during the export it  hasn't been added the starting quote. In fact in ubuntu if I type:

```
head -n 1 file.csv
```

I get this output:

```
801","40116","Hazelnut MT -L","Thursday Promo","Large","","5.9000","","801","1.0000","","3.6500","2.2500",".0000","default","","","","","Chatime","02/06/2014","09125a9cfffd4143a00e73e3b62f15f2","CB01","",".0000","5.9000","6.9000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000","0","","0","0","0","","","","","","","","","Modern Milk Tea","","","0","","","1","0","","","","","","","","0","Hau Chan","","","","","","","","","","0","","","","","","","-1","","","","","","","","","","","","0","00000000420714AA","2014-06-02","1900-01-01","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Is there some command type that can help me to add the missing starting quote?

Comment: There is, but you could also open the file in a text editor and add the quote manually.

Comment: It's a 70gb csv file. I think I cannot open it.

Comment: Oh, ok... that changes things.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the quote missing only in the first line or is it missing in every line? Just like oguz ismail I assumed that it's only missing in the first line since you only showed that one line.

Comment: @Socowi only in the first line. The next ones are with correct quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in every posix-shell:

```
printf \" | cat - file.csv > repaired-file.csv
```

If you are happy with the result you can overwrite the original

```
mv repaired-file.csv file.csv
```

Since your file is 70GB big you might want to avoid creating a second file, however this is harder than it seems. Sure, there are things like `sed`'s inplace option (`-i`) and the `sponge` utility from `moreutils`, but they do not work as in-place as you might expect. `sed -i` and `sponge` both use temporary files or hold the whole file in-memory (which does not work for 70GB anymore). A great research on true in-place editing can be found in [this blog post](https://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/). The conclusion: There are no standard-tools supporting true in-place editing. But the following `perl` one-liner should work (already adapted to your needs).

```
perl <<'EOF'
  use Tie::File;
  my @a;
  tie @a, 'Tie::File', 'path/to/your/file' or die 'Cannot tie file';
  $a[0] = '"' . $a[0];
EOF
```

---

## Benchmarks

Out of interest I ran the commands discussed here and measured their running times.

The 9.3 GiB input file `f` was generated using `seq 1000000000 > f`. Before timing a single command I always re-generated `f` and emptied the system cache using `sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. My system had enough memory to hold the whole file, but I monitored memory usage manually – all commands only used a few KB of memory.

- `printf \" | cat - f > f2; mv f2 f`   1m 05s
- `perl … # script from above`         1m 32s
- `sed -i '1s/^/"/' f`            25m 57s (also used 100% CPU the whole time)

I'm a bit surprised myself that the `cat` command was faster than the `perl` script. However, it makes sense since the `perl` script does a lot of seeks (can be seen using `strace`) whereas `cat` just copies.

**Summary:** Use the `cat` command if you have enough disk space left. If the file is bigger than the remaining free disk space on your system then use the `perl` script.